# Got an error of :Type 'Usersinterface' does not satisfy the constraints document

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Here is the screenshot of error:
 [image]

Here is the code of usersinterface:

```
export class Usersinterface {
    readonly username: string;
    readonly password: string;
}
```

Here is the code of userservices:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import {Usersdto} from './users.dto'
import {Usersinterface} from './users.interface'
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    private hashLength = 16;
    constructor(@Inject('Usersinterface') private readonly userModel: Model<Usersinterface>) {}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export class Usersinterface extends mongoose.Document {
    readonly username: string;
    readonly password: string;
}
```